# Problema ao descompactar arquivo

Tags: python, arquivo-zip, unicode

Tenho um zip que, dentro dele existem varios arquivos a serem descompactados.
Até ai tudo bem, estou usando o seguinte mtodo para dezipar o mesmo:?

```
with closing(z), zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(z.content)) as myzip:
                myzip.extractall(local_path)
```

Porem me deparei com a situação que dentro do zip existe um arquivo com unicode pode exemplo:

```
- myfile.wav
- myfile2.wav
- my§ile.wav
```

Como posso tratar esses arquivos, para descompactar eles corretamente?

Comment: Não está descompactando corretamente? O que está acontecendo?

Comment: ele nao consegue descompactar, apresenta um erro de unicode

Comment: Pode postar o erro completo, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabalhar com caracteres Unicode, é necessário acrescentar um tipo de comentário funcional no cabeçalho do script para não apresentar esse erro. Estou falando do # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, usado para esse caso. Vai aí um exemplo, para Python 2.7:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with closing(z), zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(z.content)) as myzip:
                myzip.extractall(local_path)

Não está saindo o sustenido para indicar que se trata de um comentário e nem os asteriscos na resposta entre os hífens não sei porquê quando escrevo, mas considere-os na escrita do programa.